# Find the measure $\mu$ such that $f = \int g d\mu$

Tags: integration, functional-analysis, measure-theory

I have the following equation:

$$P(x)=\int_0^\infty f(x,y) g(y)dy $$

This is, I have an equation relating P to the weighted integral of f with respect to the weight $g(y)$. I want to somehow invert this equation to get an expression for $g$ in terms of $P$ and $f$ (which I know).

I though of expressing this equation as:

$$P = \int f d\mu$$

Where the measure $\mu$ is given by $g(y)dy$. Then the problem would be for a given $P$ and $f$ to find the measure $\mu$ verifying the above equality. Is this doable? If it is, how can I do that?

I also tried applying some kind of transform to my original equation to see if I can solve it in an easier way. I was thinking of applying a Laplace transform (because of the limits of my original integral) but I have the problem that I have no delay when integrating over the $y$ variable so I can't get a simplified equation as I would get in the case of a convolution.

How can I find $g$ in terms of $P$ and $f$?

EDIT: I have been reading this last few days and I've found what is exactly what I want to solve. I have a Fredholm equation of the first kind with a continuous (kind of Gaussian) kernel. Is this kind of equations solvable analytically or the best thing that I can get is a numerical solution?